# On select, dynamically populate textarea — jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, gravity

I'm using the Gravity Forms plugin for WordPress, and I'm trying to have one of the select menus dynamically update the text in a textarea. I'm very new to jQuery, and I'd really appreciate some help understanding how to make my code work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#input_27').change(function() {
            var divetext = $('#input_27').val();
            var divewords = '';
            if (divetext == 'Standard') {
            divewords = 'All Ye Surface Sailors, aviators, fossil-fuelers, landlubbers, and other innocents Know ye and Mark ye that from (date) to (date) the inner depths of my subaqueous realm were visited by a very large black denizen.  On careful examination by my mermaids this great black fish was identified as (Name of submarine). I am informed that among the distinguished on board at that time was (Recipient name). By this my decree, this Submariner is awarded and shall bear in perpetuity the honored title of Deep Diver and shall be accorded all the perquisites and privileges that befit this exalted status.';
            }
            else if (divetext == '1st Dive') {
            divewords = 'All Ye Surface Sailors, aviators, fossil-fuelers, landlubbers, and other innocents Know ye and Mark ye that from (date) to (date) the inner depths of my subaqueous realm were visited by a very large black denizen.  On careful examination by my mermaids this great black fish was identified as (Name of submarine). I am informed that among the distinguished on board for their 1st Dive was (Recipient name). By this my decree, this Submariner is awarded and shall bear in perpetuity the honored title of Deep Diver and shall be accorded all the perquisites and privileges that befit this exalted status.';
            }
            else if (divetext == 'Last Dive') {
            divewords = 'All Ye Surface Sailors, aviators, fossil-fuelers, landlubbers, and other innocents Know ye and Mark ye that from (date) to (date) the inner depths of my subaqueous realm were visited by a very large black denizen.  On careful examination by my mermaids this great black fish was identified as (Name of submarine). I am informed that among the distinguished on board for their last time was (Recipient name). By this my decree, this Submariner is awarded and shall bear in perpetuity the honored title of Deep Diver and shall be accorded all the perquisites and privileges that befit this exalted status.';
            }
            else if (divetext == 'Honorary Submariner') {
            divewords = 'All Ye Surface Sailors, aviators, fossil-fuelers, landlubbers, and other innocents Know ye and Mark ye that from (date) to (date) the inner depths of my subaqueous realm were visited by a very large black denizen.  On careful examination by my mermaids this great black fish was identified as (Name of submarine). I am informed that among the distinguished on board at that time was (Recipient name). By this my decree, this Submariner is awarded and shall bear in perpetuity the honored title of Deep Diver and shall be accorded all the perquisites and privileges that befit this exalted status.';
            }
            else {
            divewords = 'All Ye Surface Sailors, aviators, fossil-fuelers, landlubbers, and other innocents Know ye and Mark ye that from (date) to (date) the inner depths of my subaqueous realm were visited by a very large black denizen.  On careful examination by my mermaids this great black fish was identified as (Name of submarine). I am informed that among the distinguished on board at that time was (Recipient name). By this my decree, this Submariner is awarded and shall bear in perpetuity the honored title of Deep Diver and shall be accorded all the perquisites and privileges that befit this exalted status.';
            }
            $("#input_20").val(divewords);    
        });​
    });
</script>
```

(Code also at: http://pastie.org/pastes/5476003 )

input_27 — ID of the select menu.
input_20 — ID of the text area.

In short, I'd like the language in the textarea to change depending on which item they select from the dropdown.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: looks like it should work to me. what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the text area when I make a selection.
I could link the form, but it's a multi-page form and the particular field is pretty deep in (so a PITA to get to).

Comment: ok, try to debug: if you don't have firebug yet, get it and use it with firefox. then put the following line `console.log(divetext)` under `var divetext = $('#input_27').val();` and see what the value is. the problem probably lies somewhere there. alternatively try to set `divetext` manually so you can find out where the problem is - the `if` conditions or the setting of the `divetext` value.

Comment: Nothing shows in the console about divetext.

Comment: using firebug's console, type into the command line (on the bottom): `console.log($('#input_27').val();)`. If that is empty then your `#input_27` doesn't pass any values and you found your problem. Posting your html structure could also help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Please replace this code:

```
var divetext = $('#input_27').val();
```

TO

```
var divetext = $('#input_27:selected').text();
```